# How to show full html content on click of Print option using Angular8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, printing

I am working on Angular8 application, based on selection of dropdown, i have to print the whole html present based on selection of dropdown to be printed as shown in demo.

But here, i am not able to see the selected dropdown value, also contents displayed on the right side are hidden, and when the content is huge, i have added scroll in Additional comment section, when i click on print, i am able to see the scroll but not the content. Please help me to solve this issue.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmff4a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:

```
   public downloadPdf() {
     var printContent = document.getElementById('pdfDownload');
     this.verticalScrollTrue = false;
    $('pdfOpenHide').attr('hidden', true);
  let documentClone = $("html").clone();
    let printContainer = "printwrap";
    documentClone[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = "<div id='" + printContainer + "'>" + printContent.innerHTML + "</div>";
    let WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=300,top=0,width=1000,height=700,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.write(documentClone.html());
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    setTimeout(() => {
      WinPrint.print();
      WinPrint.close();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the scroll remove the css class "vert-scrollable-150".

Change:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush vert-scrollable-150">
```

To

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. when you select value from dropdown, you are able to see selected dropdown value, and Note Text values, and Additional Comments, so when i click on Print, i am able to see only additional comments with only Note Text kind of labels

Comment: are those fields must be inputs? you can change `<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticnoteText" value="{{ selectedNoteDetails?.noteText}}">` to just `{{ selectedNoteDetails?.noteText}}` then it will be visible on the print form

Comment: They are not inputs, all displayed are in read only mode

Comment: yeah, so just use brackets  {{ value }} without html <input>

Comment: even though i am not able to get those, and UI should have scroll, but when i click on Print, that scroll must be removed and all UI to be shown in the Print screen, but in application scroll to be shown

Comment: also the selected dropdown value name is also not shown

Comment: you can use ngClass condition to show/hide scroll (css class)  
I'm not sure why select value is not shown, but the workaround would add that value somewhere on the UI and show/hide it using print button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221868/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-qual09).